# How can I get the content type name inside the hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() hook?

Tags: 8, forms

I need to obtain the content type name inside an implementation of the `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` hook for the node edit/add form to made some validations.

I can't find any node object reference using `kint()` to access to the `$node->getType()` value.

I need to do a validation like this:

```
if ($node->getType() == 'article') {
...
}
```

So, how can I get the content type name inside the `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` hook?

Comment: What are you using for BASE_FORM_ID?

Comment: @Jaypan is for the node edit/create page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the node from the form object.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  /* @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

  if (!$node->getType() == 'article') {
    // ....
  }
}
```

Note that `getEntity()` doesn't exist on `\Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface`, which is why it doesn't show up as a method in an IDE. It only exists on `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormInterface`, you can add an explicit instance of for that.

Comment: Thanks, I see now why I never found it, how can I add the interface?

Comment: Hi you says in your answer: "you can add an explicit interface of for that." but how I can do it?

Comment: That should have said instanceof, not interface os, aka if ($form_state instanceof EntityFormInterface), you can use that with a generic hook_form_alter() to identify/alter any entity form.

Comment: This works. Thank you so much, Berdir

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I found using the `kint()` output with the help of the [Search Kint](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_kint) module to find the content type name is this:

```
$form['#process'][1][0]->getTargetBundle()
```

Is working, but is not the best way to obtain the value.

```
if ($form['#process'][1][0]->getTargetBundle() == 'article') {
 ...
}
```